# Deciphering an adb logcat

Tags: c++, android-ndk, logcat

My android game keeps crashing intermittently. I am having trouble pinpointing what the cause is. The crash seems to happen at random during active game play. I use the SDLActivity java file to interface with SDL. Here are the results of a ndk-stack trace that I ran.

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'Huawei/SCL-L01/hwSCL-Q:5.1.1/HuaweiSCL-
L01/C432B160:user/release-keys'
pid: 28222, tid: 28261, name: SDLThread  >>> com.example.proj <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 0 (SI_USER), fault addr 0x53b
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  330):
     #00 pc 0002af24  /data/app/com.example.proj-1/lib/arm/libmain.so
     (Game::Render()+6387): Routine Game::distribute() at C:/Users/HelloWorld/Desktop/NewbieGame/app/src/main/jni/src/Game.cpp:365

Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  330):
     #01 pc 000413a9  /data/app/com.example.proj-1/lib/arm/libmain.so
     (Game::Event(SDL_Event*, unsigned int)+328):
     Routine bool std::__ndk1::operator==<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>,
                  std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,
                  std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*)
                  at D:/ndk/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/string:3854

Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  330):
     #02 pc 0001379f 
     /data/app/com.example.proj-1/lib/arm/libmain.so
     (SDL_main+954): Routine $a at libgcc2.c:?

Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  330): 
    #03 pc 0001326f  /data/app/com.example.proj-1/lib/arm/libmain.so 
    (Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit+422): Routine $a at libgcc2.c:?

Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

I can hardly make sense of what this logcat means. I've been to the files reported by the logcat and see nothing that causes the crashes. Is anybody able to explain what exactly these log messages might mean?

Comment: What's at `C:/Users/HelloWorld/Desktop/NewbieGame/app/src/main/jni/src/Game.cpp:365` ?  Looks like it is doing a `==` test between a `std::string` and a `char const *`.

Comment: I recompiled my code and this time included -Werror -Wall which changed all of my warnings to errors. I then cleaned up the errors in the source code. The game seems alot more stable now, and crashes alot less and less randomly so far. I'm now only gettting a SIGBUS error.